# Como usar correctamente el return dentro de un for?

Tags: javascript, bucles, undefined

estoy recien empezando a usar Javascript y cuando intento hacer un return con todos los valores de la tabla del 6, la funcion solo me retorna el 0

```
function tablaDelSeis(){
    for(var i=0;i<=60;i=i+6){
        return(i);
    }
}
```

No obstante, Usando "console.log" en lugar del "return", si me retorna los valores de la tabla del 6 pero la consigna me pide que la resuelva usando return.

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: el |return| no es mas que un retorno por lo que una vez ejecutado concluye la funcion y retorna el valor en este caso 0....

Comment: Estas teniendo un problema de concepto, `console.log()` lo que hace es imprimir valores en consola, exclusivamente esto. Por otro lado `return` lo que hace es resolver una función (no imprime nada en consola), es decir, dar el valor de retorno de una función y finalizar la misma. En tu caso solo se llega a la primera iteración porque el return finaliza el ciclo for.

Answer (score 3):

La sentencia `return` debe usarse solo cuando ya terminó la función, si lo pones dentro del ciclo, solo va a haber una iteración.

```
function tablaDelSeis() {
    for(var i=0;i<=60;i=i+6){
        // Aquí finaliza la función y devuelve solo el primer valor de i
        return i;
    }
}
```

Luego dices esto:

> No obstante, Usando "console.log" en lugar del "return", si me retorna los valores de la tabla del 6

No es que te devuelva valores, simplemente los muestra en la consola.

```
function tablaDelSeis(){
    for(var i=0;i<=60;i=i+6){
        // Se muestran todos los valores que tome i
        console.log(i);
    }
    // La función no devuelve valor, porque no hay return
}
```

Deberías crear una variable (tal vez una cadena) para almacenar los resultados, la llenas dentro del ciclo y, al salir, devuelves esa variable.

```
function tablaDelSeis(){
    // Definir variable para almacenar resultados
    let result = '';
    for(let i = 0; i <= 60; i = i + 6){
        // Agregar valores separados por coma
        result += i + ', ';
    }
    // Devolver cadena resultante
    return result;
}
```

La función te va a devolver la siguiente salida:

```
0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60,
```

Como puedes ver, sobra una coma y espacio al final, pero ya se acerca un poco a lo que quieres obtener. Podrías usar [subString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) para arreglarla.

Tal vez el `for` debería iniciar con 6, para evitar ese cero.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que el `return`, además de devolver un valor, también finaliza inmediatamente la ejecución de la función donde es llamado. En tu caso inicializas la variable i con un valor de cero, y le pides en cada iteración que se incremente de 6 en 6. Como el return finaliza la función de manera inmediata, nunca llega a incrementarse. Lo que pudieras hacer es guardar el valor de i en un array en cada iteración y luego retornarías ese array:

```
function tablaDelSeis () {
    var Resultado = []
    for (var i=0; i<=60; i=i+6) Resultado.push (i)
    return Resultado
}
```

Aunque creo en lo personal que el número 0 no deberías devolverlo, en ese caso la variable i debe iniciar en 6.

Si necesitas convertir ese array en una cadena, puedes usar el método `join` y usar el separador que desees:

```
return Resultado.join (" / ")
//Devolvería 0 / 6 / 12 / 18 etc... Pudieras usar el separador que quieras.
```